# Trying to draw grid ends up in drawing long rectangle

Tags: android, grid, rectangles

I'd like to draw a grid. Therefore I've got

```
private int GRID_WIDTH = 6;  <----Amount of columns
private int GRID_HEIGHT = 6; <----Amount of rows
private int GRID_SIZE; = 50  <----Width and height of a cell
```

Now I am trying to draw them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < GRID_WIDTH; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < GRID_HEIGHT; j++) {
        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(i*GRID_SIZE + 5, j*GRID_SIZE + 5, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE), paint);
    }
}
```

The "5" after each coordinate should make a gap between two rectangles. 
This should end up in some nice grid, but as result I see multiple rectangles pushed together, without these 5px padding between them. No matter what I choose as padding, It resuls in following image: (Here the padding is set to 20 instead of 5...)

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that the Rect constructor signature is:

`Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

and you're doing like:

`Rect(int left, int top, int width, int height)`

Notice the difference in the last two arguments. You must do like this:

```
int left = i * (GRID_SIZE + 5);
int top = j * (GRID_SIZE + 5);
int right = left + GRID_SIZE;
int bottom = top + GRID_SIZE;
canvas.drawRect(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), paint);
```

Comment: int left = i * GRID_SIZE + 5; 

didn't work but

int left = i * (GRID_SIZE + 5); 

did

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: same for top= j*GRID_SIZE + 5. Use top = j * (GRID_SIZE + 5).